# Why is $\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\overline{\mathbf{x}}^T\mathbf{u_i})\mathbf{u_i} = \overline{\mathbf{x}}$ true?

Tags: linear-algebra

$\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\overline{\mathbf{x}}^T\mathbf{u_i})\mathbf{u_i} = \overline{\mathbf{x}}$ where $\mathbf{u_i}^T\mathbf{u_j} = 1$ for all $i \neq j$ and $0$ otherwise. Finally let $\overline{\mathbf{x}} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\mathbf{x_i}}$.

I have tried too many ways to derive this result while failing.. Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the canonical expansion of a vector in terms of an orthonormal basis. One way to check that this identity is true is to verify that the inner product of both sides with each one of the vectors $u_i$ is the same. Indeed, by the orthogonality relations,  for each $1\leq j\leq n$ you have

$$\overline{u_j}^T\sum_{i=1}^n(\overline{x}^Tu_i)u_i=(\overline{x}^Tu_j)$$

Comment: I see the logic there using orthonormality but I still don't see how we end up with $\overline{\mathbf{x}}$?

Comment: Well, if you have two vectors with the same components relative to some orthonormal basis (or any basis, for that matter), then they must be equal.